# Best way to build a many-to-many relation postgres database with hierarchy

Tags: database, postgresql, data-modeling, supabase

I'm sure this question has been answered many times but I couldn't find a simple answer to this one. I'm creating a database with components that could be nested.

Component 1

- Component 2
- Component 3

Component 4

- Component 5
- Component 6

  - Component 7
  - Component 8

---

This could also be ordered differently with the same components

Component 3

- Component 1
- Component 4

Component 5

- Component 7
- Component 8

  - Component 2
  - Component 6

---

What would be the best way to build my Postgres database?

I have a `components` table but I'm not sure how should I build the relation. If I create a relation table with `parent` / `child`, how do I get the multiple ordering?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/trying-to-represent-a-tree-structure-using-postgre first search result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Comment: https://medium.com/notes-from-a-messy-desk/representing-trees-in-postgresql-cbcdae419022